# how to distribute a lua file with c++

Tags: c++, c, lua, love2d

I know how to do stuff with Lua states and what not but what i don't understand is how you would distribute the final program with a seperate lua file because say you have a .exe and a lua file in the same directory how would I make it so that it is all one executable like how Löve 2d uses

```
copy /b
```

to append the lua file to the Löve 2d interpreter so it can be distributed.
could someone possibly explain how this works.

many thanks 
Blazing

Comment: Are you asking how to combine the two files into one file? Or are you asking how to *not* do that and instead how to distribute *two* files and use the `.lua` file from the executable?

Comment: I'm asking how to combine them into one file similar to that of love2d so that when said application is distributed the user isn't tempted to poke around the .lua file and so that people implementing the c++ don't need to know it and can focus on just using lua

Comment: `copy /b` just merged the two files by stuffing one file on the end of the other file I think. So how to use that is a question of how to find the other file at the end of your file. I don't know if there's a specific way to do it but you could always just open yourself and read backwards from the end until you find your header/marker and then load it.

Comment: https://love2d.org/wiki/Game_Distribution like what is described under creating a Windows executable.

Comment: Yeah. Like I said I don't know how love is doing it specifically but at its simplest what I said should work I believe.

Comment: I'll try it out and then get back to you once I've tested it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could embed the lua code directly into your C++ source in a raw string literal like so:

```
const auto lua_code = R"lua(
...lua code here...
)lua";
```

Comment: I understand that this is possible and i will use this if absolutely necessary but i would rather have the code in a seperate file so that it can be edited by people who aren't as proficient

Comment: @BlazingCode Then you should have a build system which converts your Lua file to C code and inserts it before compiling your executable.